# GFD files import and read and export into CSV with python

Tags: python

I am trying to import GFD files and read and export into CSV with Python, but  I keep having an error.

I want to know which library to read and open GFD files in Python.
I was working with easygdf on https://nb.anaconda.cloud/jupyterhub/.

`conda install easygdf`

```
import easygdf

d = easygdf.load("A-1OG.gdf")
```

Comment: What was wrong with using `easygdf.load`? Is the problem that easygdf is for GDF files but you are trying to import "GFD" files?

Comment: `GDF` -> `GFD`,  this looks like a typo.

Comment: also, the link in the question does not work.

Comment: the link is only for Python online Compiler

Comment: GDFIOError: Input is not a GDF file